# Send data from Express JS server to update the text in my current HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, post

Ultimately I want to receive POST data from index.js (Which I have already done), Process it and then change the value on the  fields which I have got my values from.

For example:

```js
app.post("/", funtion (req, res) {
    data = req.body // The data I am getting
    // Proccesing it
    newdata = "blabla"
    res.send("?") // How do I return the data to the input fields I got the values from so the user can see them?
});
```

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="computer" value="">
    <input type="text" name="ip" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Button">
 </form>
```

Comment: You need to serve a new page as a response.

Comment: You'll have to do it client-side. It should handle a JSON answer from the server and update your input fields like classical JS.

Answer (score 0):

You should use res.send() to return a JSON response with the values to the client.

```
res.send({computer:'MyComputer',ip:'192.0.0.1'});
```

On the client side you should receive the JSON response and render it on your form.